# Distinct en una sola columna

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, distinct

Tengo la siguiente columna como ejemplo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que intento es que me devuelva todos los resultados excepto los que en código sean iguales, en este caso me interesan solo los del gestor 6, quedaría algo así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Perdón, Sql Server 2014.

Comment: ¿Quieres decir que necesitas los resultados en los que el código sea único o que pertenezcan al gestor 6?

Answer (score 0):

Una de las opciones más simples es utilizar la función de ventana row_number, y numerar las filas particionando por código y ordenando por el gestor.

En tú escenario:

```
create table dbo.gestores (Gestor int, codigo int, precio int)
go
insert into dbo.gestores (Gestor, codigo, precio)
values
(2,555,10),
(6,555,5),
(2,666,10),
(6,666,5),
(2,777,15),
(6,888,15);
go
```

En una tabla de expresión común obtenemos todos los registros de gestores y numeramos cada fila, particionando por código.

```
With cte as (
    Select *
        , ROW_NUMBER() 
          over(PARTITION by codigo order by gestor desc) as row
    from dbo.gestores
    )
    select c.Gestor as [Gestor]
         , c.codigo as [código]
         , c.precio as [precio]
    from cte c
        where row = 1;
```

[image: Resultado]

La clave está en que cada vez que cambie el código row_number numerará empezando por 1 y que la ordenación la realizamos por el gestor de modo descendente.

Si la obligatoriedad que expresas de que sea el gestor 6 en caso de duplicados, fuese si o si, puedes cambiar el order by utilizando una expresión case.

```
With cte as (
    Select *
        , ROW_NUMBER() 
          over(PARTITION by codigo 
          order by case when gestor = 6 then 0 else gestor end ) as row
    from dbo.gestores
    )
    select c.Gestor as [Gestor]
         , c.codigo as [código]
         , c.precio as [precio]
        from cte c
        where row = 1;
```

Obteniendo el mismo resultado, pero fijando el gestor 6 como inicio de la ordenación ya que está es ascendente y le hemos indicado al motor que si la fila que esté evaluando tiene para esa columna un valor de 6 le ponga 0. Partiendo de la base de que los códigos sean números mayores, este será siempre el primero.

[Numerar filas Row number](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/11/row-number-numerar-filas/)

[Tablas de expresión común](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/with-cte-tablas-de-expresion-comun-1/)